# Apply before and after CSS rule on element's content

Tags: html, css

I have the following code

```
<div class="testimonial_description_inner" style="width: 640px;">
    We can’t solve problems by using the same kind of thinking we used when we created them.
    <strong class="testimonial_author">- Einstein</strong>
    <p class="testimonial_meta"></p>
</div>
```

I want to add an opening and closing quote only on the part of:

`We can’t solve problems by using the same kind of thinking we used when we created them.`

When I use it like this:

```
.testimonial_description_inner:before {
    content: "\201C";
    font-size: 40px;
    font-family: Georgia, serif;
}

.testimonial_description_inner:after {
    content: "\201C";
    font-size: 40px;
    font-family: Georgia, serif;
}
```

the closing quote is at the end of the whole `div`. How can I choose only the inner part to apply the CSS rule without changing the HTML code?

Comment: Where's the element with the class `.testimonial_description_inner`?

Comment: @j08691 sorry.. Typo during the copy paste... I updated it.

Comment: not sure if this is possible without touching the HTML. Since you don't have a `p` tag around your quote, you can't target it outside of using the entire `div` or `body` to select the content (at least without JS). If you were able to add a `p` tag with a class, you could simply apply the `:before` and `:after` to that class and be on your way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add the closing quote as a `before` pseudoelement on `.testimonial_author`.

I've used `display: inline-block` to line it up with the preceding text, but `float: right` might also work...

```css
.testimonial_description_inner:before {
  content: "\201C";
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: Georgia, serif;
}

.testimonial_author:before {
  content: "\201C";
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: Georgia, serif;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="testimonial_description_inner" style="width: 640px;">
  We can’t solve problems by using the same kind of thinking we used when we created them.
  <strong class="testimonial_author">- Einstein</strong>
  <p class="testimonial_meta"></p>
</div>
```